# How did 'patriate' develop to mean 'transfer ... from a mother country to its former dependency'?

Tags: etymology

What's an intuitive derivation behind [ODO's definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/leverage) that helps to internalise its meaning:

> **to patriate** = Transfer control over (a constitution) from a mother country to its former dependency:
>
> [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=patriate&searchmode=none): 1966, in Canadian English (perhaps coined by Lester B. Pearson) in reference to constitutional laws, probably a back-formation from repatriate.
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriation): The word "patriation" was invented in Canada as a back-formation from "repatriation" (returning to one's country). As the Canadian constitution was originally a British law, **it could not "return to" Canada**.

So I know that this is a Canadian term, but what's the relationship between **it could not "return to" Canada** and the elimination of the prefix 're'? How's this word a 'back-formation'?

Comment: It's either *How did [word] come to mean...?* or *How did [word] evolve to mean...?* not "develop".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Would you mind explaining why not? I'd love to learn from mistakes.

Comment: I have to think about that. I'll come back to you! I suspect it's to do with collocation, a word doesn't develop, the meaning of a word can change, be modified, expand, and evolve but "develop" sounds a bit off. Your phrase is grammatical, and understandable, but perhaps it's not very idiomatic. Hmmm....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Patria* is derived from Latin (*[fatherland](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:patria)*) and, in English, means

> One’s native country or homeland:
>   *they remained faithful to their patria, Spain* [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

When a colonial power transfers power to a colony, the old father/motherland is no longer the homeland. The former colony now becomes its own homeland. At that moment, a new *patria* has been created.

While the current usage of *patriate* may be based on a back-formation from *re-patriate*, the logic holds.

The phrase in the Wikipedia article merely points out that, as Canada became independent, it was not going back, but forward. *Repatriation* of Canada or its constitution would be re-attaching it to the former homeland, England.

Answer (score 1):

"Repatriate" means "to bring back to its original land/country," the prefix "re-" here giving the coming back home part of the meeting.

Historically, as a British colony and later as a dominion of the British Empire, Canada did not have a home-grown constitution. It was originally a British document, so could not logically "return home" to Canada in the sense of coming back to the land where it originated, hence the perceived need to have a word indicating a "one-way trip."

If the Canadians ever, for some reason, returned responsibility for the Constitution to GB, it would be repatriated.